# Maintaining two almost identical gits, one commit apart?

Tags: git

I am working on a project and I have two branches configured for it: One is connected to a remote server and the other is connected to a local server.

The difference between those two is several lines of code, mainly indicating the server address and desired port. I want to keep the two branch as identical as possible with the only difference being the connection settings (a single commit). Doing a git rebase all the time is tedious, and I couldn't find any convenient way to do it. Is it even possible? 
Thanks!!

Comment: What about having a local configuration file so that you read different values depending on a environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is data (not code). This should be in a separate file (or in your case, maybe just an environment variable) that can be stored separately. Keep the code base the same.

Comment: It sounds like a good idea! I'll check how to do that in my Environment (Android Studio). If I manage to set the data in a seperate file, how do I manage that in Git and switch between them? Should I just exclude it from the Git and replace it manually every time I want to switch servers?

Comment: Usually, your "server" environment will have some way of specifying config files/entries separate from the source code. That's where you should do it.